# how do I check, how many times printing command is run on my windows

Tags: windows, printing, event-log

I have to check for a specific time range, how many times the printing command is executed on my PC/Windows….

Is Operating system make any log of printing commands...? If yes How and where i found it...?

Comment: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/check-printer-logs-54952.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In compmgmt.msc, navigate in the left pane to System Tools -> Event Viewer -> Applications and Service Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Print Service -> Operational

In the right pane, click "Enable log"

This is also where you will look for the log entries. To find just print job completions, look for event ID 307. The "Filter Current Log..." command in the right pane will allow you to select just that event ID and select for time ranges.

You didn't say which Windows version. The above applies to Windows 7/Server 2008 R2 and later.